# PMing member on Discord upon joining

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am new to Javascript and am currently writing a bot for Discord. I want to have it PM a message to new users when they join, but I get an error that I can not seem to resolve

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    message.author.send('Welcome to Tiltopia! Make sure you read the rules in <#627667348249116713> and join the server!');
});
```

That is what I have but I get an error saying

> ReferenceError: message is not defined

Whenever someone joins. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.send('Welcome to Tiltopia! Make sure you read the rules in <#627667348249116713> and join the server!');
});
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to reference `message`, which is not defined in this case. The `guildMemberAdd` event outputs the `member`, which is a GuildMember.

Just replace `message.author` with `member` and you'll be fine.

```js
member.send('message');
```

Hope this helps.